# Play 2, Fakerequest to test route but without executing controller method

Tags: security, testing, playframework, playframework-2.0, integration-testing

I am trying to test the security of my Play! 2 application. To do that I am calling every possible page one after the other using FakeRequests.
My problem is that I don't want to execute the controllers method but only check that a secured page is not accessible if no logged in ( I did this by checking the redirection to the login page) and to check that a non secured page is effectively called.
In the case of a secured page no problem, but if the page is not secured it will perform the controller method and if this method call the database then the test will fail because I don't plan to execute this test with a database running. I want to isolate it, because it is not the purpose of this test.

Here is a typical instruction that I use to test a non secured page :

```
redirectLocation(route(FakeRequest(GET, "/eventStream/52c6a70b010000010043bf2d")).get).get must not equal "/"
```

How to verify that there is no redirection to the login page without executing the code of the controller method ?
Is it possible ?

Comment: Assuming your security is working as it should, the controller function shouldn't be called if you're denied access, and the request should get stopped at the filter level.

Comment: In fact my problem is to check the unsecured page not the contrary

Comment: That's not possible in this form, then. Because in order to get a response that's not `SEE_OTHER`, you'll have to pass through the controller function. It'd be better to test the method of authentication/authorization separately.

Comment: You mean a UnitTest with only the Authorization tested ?

Comment: Yes. If you don't want to execute the controller function, then don't call it. Testing authentication/authorization logic ought to be done separately. That's what *unit* testing is, after all.

Comment: Yes, to do so I would have to mock the controller I guess, but unfortunately it is impossible to do it simply with Play in Scala since the controllers are Scala Object (singleton) and thus are not mockable (except with Slacalamock but it's use is really too constraining for the application). Do you see another possibility to  avoid the call of this method ?

Comment: How are you checking the Auth? With a Filter or something like that? It sounds more like you should be testing that filter than the routed call itself.